# UK visa valid for the next 5 months. Can I apply for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, france, italy

I have migrated from India to the UK on a short m-term ICT Tier 2 visa. I want to visit Europe, and want to apply for a Schengen visa.

However, my UK visa is valid only until August, i.e., 5 months. If I apply now, will my application be considered,
or should I get my UK visa renewed before applying for a Schengen visa?

Comment: How soon do you want to visit the Schengen area?

Comment: Generally Schengen countries allow for the completion of travel atmost 3 months before the expiry of your visa. So chances are you will get a visa.Safer is to get it renewed and then apply. Many countries i.e. France, give long visas, so you might get only a month's visa rather than a 6 month visa. But vfs is a useless place to apply for visa application and you might get a date maybe a month in the future.

Comment: @DumbCoder Just noted your comment. Why do you feel VFS is useless? I am considering going through them to avoid traveling to another city for my visa application.

Answer (score 2):

Approving Schengen visa usually takes about two-three weeks. Don't worry and make an application for Schengen.

Where to apply on visa depends of your travelling marshrut. Usually it is a country where you will spend most time of your trip.

To get Schengen visa fast without any problems you need to provide some documents:

- Two-way Air tickets
- Proof of sufficient finance
- Proof that you will not overstay in EU illegaly - for you it may be valid visa to UK and explanation about your plans on the future
- Also it's recomended to include description of your marshrut and book of hotels where you will stay

Enjoy your travel!

Comment: I have tier 2 work visa and I landed UK at 20th August. Is there any minimum stay required(at least 3 months completed in UK) before I apply for Schenegan visa? One of my friend applied to German visa, and his application got rejected.