# Schengen Visa from UK for an Indian working in UK on Tier2 ICT visa

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens

I have an Indian passport and currently I am working in UK on Tier2 ICT visa. I need to go to Switzerland on a business visit. Please advise whether I can get Schengen visa while in UK and do I get some advantage due to UK Tier 2 ICT visa?

Comment: That is somewhat answered here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25263/uk-visa-valid-for-next-5-months-can-i-apply-for-schengen-visa

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can apply and receive a Schengen from the UK if your application is successful. And yes, holding a T2 lowers the risk that you will breach the t's and c's of a Schengen. However, there are lots of other factors that get considered, so a T2 alone does not guarantee your application will be successful.

Comment: I have tier 2 work visa and I landed UK at 20th August. Is there any minimum stay required(at least 3 months completed in UK) before I apply for Schenegan visa? One of my friend applied to German visa, and his application got rejected.

Comment: @Rahul press the 'ask question' button to ask your question. This thread is reserved for the asker of this question